# What data transformations does curl's --data option perform?

Tags: curl

I recently used curl's `--data` option to upload some JSON to a server, and after reading the manpage, I'm not sure whether I can have faith that it got there intact.

curl's [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) *explicitly* describes one difference between curl's [`--data`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d)/[`--data-ascii`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-ascii) and [`--data-binary`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) options; namely, that when the `@filename` syntax is used to make curl read data from a file, `--data` will strip newlines from the file but `--data-binary` will not.

However, the man page *also* makes it sound like there are more differences. The following passage from the description of `--data-binary` can only be reasonably interpreted to mean that there are certain 'conversions' besides newline removal that `--data` does on the data it is given:

> #### --data-binary <data>
>
> ...
>
> ... Data is posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except that newlines and carriage returns are preserved **and conversions are never done**. *(emphasis mine)*

What are these mysterious "conversions"? Do they even exist? They are not documented in the manual's section on the `--data` option, nor can I discover them through experimentation. The obvious things that one might expect the `--data` option to transform (like ampersands, slashes, hashes, question marks, equals signs, Chinese characters, or [grinning cat faces with smiling eyes](http://emojipedia.org/grinning-cat-face-with-smiling-eyes/)) all get sent intact and unchanged.

So what is the manual talking about?

Answer (score 3):

> What are these mysterious "conversions"?

Without the binary flag `stdin` is read in text mode (this makes a difference on Windows), and, on platforms that need it (IBM mainframes and the like), data is re-encoded from charset `IBM-1047` (a.k.a. `EBCDIC`) to `ISO8859-1` using `iconv(3)`.  There is also a difference in the way data length (as passed to `Content-Length` and friends) is computed.